# Aligning an image and an anchor tag inside a figure tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am stuck and out of ideas, I tried to achieve the following with flexbox and failed.

What I am trying to achieve is to have an `img`tag centered inside a `figure` tag and have an `a` tag which contains an another `img` tag(like a button to show a different version of the first image) align at the bottom right corner of the same `figure` tag.
Let me try to explain with an image: [image: Explanation]

Here **A** is our figure tag, **B** is our first image and **C** is our anchor tag which itself contains another image.
**The A is sized at 350px by 280px**
**The B is a transparent png of varying sizes, but always a lot smaller then the A**
**The C contains a 20px by 20px image**
The container `div#gallery` contains many `figure` tags

Here is what I have right now.

```html
<div id="gallery" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: center;">
  <figure style="background-color:#2A3132; width: 350px; height: 280px">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/110x110">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30">
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

What I understand is that we can not have **C** inside **A** because then it misaligned the **B**

Comment: flex and margin could help too without position : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGbgGyY

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used `position:absolute` for positioning that small image. As mentioned by OP there is no chance for overlapping the images so it won't be problematic.

```css
#gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #2A3132;
  width: 350px;
  height: 280px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.sm-img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <figure class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/110x110">
    <a class="sm-img" href="#">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30">
    </a>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't realize that I had to mix flex with positioning :D Awesome thanks.